# Why is it "play" instead of "plays" in "What we’re seeing *play out* there are..."?

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

I'm having trouble understanding the grammatical structure of the two sentences below.

Shouldn't it be "play**s** out" instead of "play out" in both of these sentences, since the subject is "what"? As in, "what is playing out(what is happening now) in Ukraine..."

> "In the context of the horrors of *what* we’re seeing **play out** in Ukraine, the day to day running of a football club pales into insignificance."

> “*What* we’re seeing **play out** there are the somewhat toxic politics of national security, which have swamped countries around the West since 9/11,”

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Maybe it will help to rephrase the sentence like this: "We are seeing **something** play out." There is something that is being played out in Ukraine, and most of us see it. "What" is related to "seeing." **"What" is the "something"** that we are **seeing**. So **play out** just describes how we are seeing that thing. We are not seeing it **collapse**, we are not seeing it **expand rapidly**, we are simply seeing it **play out**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's exactly the same construction as this:

- He walks.
- I see him walk.

The "walk" is the infinitive, which is following our main verb. An example that makes clear that it's the infinitive is:

- She is silly.
- I saw her be silly.

So:

- What plays out in Ukraine...
- What we're seeing play out in Ukraine...

Comment: Yes, but you should explain _why_ the subordinate verb must be a non-finite form, either a plain form or a gerund-participle (_ing_) form.

Answer (score 3):

"In the context of the horrors of what **we’re seeing play out** in Ukraine, the day to day running of a football club pales into insignificance."

**we're seeing** is followed by a **bare form of the verb play out**.

Compare:

"In the context of the horrors of what **is playing out** in Ukraine, the day to day running of a football club pales into insignificance."

That would be third person continuous. And of course, present simple here does not work as present simple is for general statements.

Answer (score 1):

> *In the context of the horrors of* [*what we’re seeing play out in*
> *Ukraine*], the day to day running of a football club pales into*
> *insignificance*.

> [*What we’re seeing play out there*] *are the somewhat toxic politics of*
> *national security, which have swamped countries around the West since*
> *9/11*.

In both examples, the bracketed element is a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction where the word "what" (meaning "that which") is simultaneously head of noun phrase and subject of the embedded "play" clause. "See" is a catenative verb here that  requires as its complement either an infinitival clause with the plain form verb "play" or a gerund-participial clause with the gerund-participial verb "playing". The author chose the former.